# Tabulator : Row Selections Column - Filter to show selected Rows

Tags: javascript, tabulator, suitescript2.0

I have a nice Tabulator table showing an item list.

For the first column I have a `rowSelection` type formatter for users to select the row.

```
{
    formatter: "rowSelection",
    titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
    titleFormatterParams: {
        rowRange: "active"
    },
    align: "center",
    frozen: true,
    headerSort: false,
}
```

And it does it's job with selections persisting through filtering of other columns.

[image]

Is it possible to add a headerfilter to the `rowSelection` column to a) clear other filters, and b) filter the table to show only selected rows?